# SQL Distinct Lines

Tags: sql

I have the date below;

```
Have            
Client_Name         ParentCompanyGUID        RP 
Formula One LTD     83E2A813-E5D3-4BC3       Hayes, Charles 
Formula One LTD     83E2A813-E5D3-4BC3       Martindale, Avril
```

Want

```
Client_Name        ParentCompanyGUID    RP1             RP2
Formula One LTD    83E2A813-E5D3-4BC3   Hayes, Charles  Martindale, Avril
```

Would you happen to know the best way to transpose a non distinct dataset and create a distinct row with new columns being populated?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select Client_Name, . . .,
       max(case when Seq = 1 then RP end) as RP1,
       max(case when Seq = 2 then RP end) as RP2 
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by Client_Name, . . order by ?) as Seq
      from table
     ) t
group by Client_Name, . . .;
```

However, you haven't stated any *DBMS* but most of *DBMS* has support of *analytical* function

`partition` clause include columns which has possible duplicate values.

Comment: That works fine. Thank you. Would you happen to know how to amend that query so that the sequence number is dynamic so you wouldn't have to state Seq=1, Seq=2 etc?

Comment: @Chris. . . That is dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two values, the simplest method is `max()`, `min()`:

```
select client_name, ParentCompanyGUID, min(rp) as rp_1, max(rp) as rp_2
from t
group by client_name, ParentCompanyGUID;
```

This does not work for more than two pivoted columns in the result set.  If you need a separate column for each value, and the number of value is unknown, then you need to use dynamic SQL -- which is highly specific to your database product.

An alternative is to concatenate all the values together into a single column.  That also depends on the database.